# Update multiple previous actvity from current activity

Tags: android

In my app my 1st activity can open 3rd Activity and 2nd Activity, So when i open 3rd Activty from 2nd Activity then I want to update data of 2nd and 1st Activity.
How I can do that?? My flow is 1->2 , 1->3 , 2->3 . From 3rd Activity update 2nd and 1st Activity data.

Answer (score 0):

While opening the activities pass the data using [`Intents`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html) or [`Bundle`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Bundle.html) and then update them in `onCreate`. Also, you can use [EventBus](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus) to transfer the data